# mercurial revert file in subrepo

Tags: mercurial

If I do

```
hg revert subrepo/foo
```

then it fails as I need to specify -R for the subrepo. I'd rather not have to do this so I wrote a script to do it. Works fine, but I hope/wonder if there is a better way?

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $*; do
    repo=$(echo $file | cut -d'/' -f-1)
    file=$(echo $file | cut -d'/' -f2-)

    if [ -f $repo/$file ]; then
      hg revert -R $repo $repo/$file
    fi
done
```